# C++ - Logging statements according to the level

Tags: c++

I have the following statements:

```
static Logging::Logger* common_logger = new Logging::Logger(Logging::Logger::LEVEL);
```

In the Logger.h i have

```
  class Logger {
public:

    enum LEVEL {
        Debug,
        Warning,
        Notification,
        Error
    };
  }
```

I have included the file Logger.h inside my another class as :

```
    Logging::log(CustomDialog::logger, Logging::Entry, CustomDialog::CLASSNAME, "CustomDialog");
```

I need to know if this is the right way to do the reason why i am doing this is to get logs based upon the level.

Regards,

Comment: Why not simply use one of the [open source logging libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696321/best-logging-framework-for-native-c) and save yourself a lot of effort?

Comment: does those have the same supposrt please suggest something

Comment: Yes, they do.There are a number of open source logging frameworks which you can simly use as libraries.Check out the link i added in my first comment.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/) - it's easy to use and contains just about every feature you might want in a logging framework for C++.  It's extensible, it can be configured through configuration files, and it even supports remote logging out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ACE_DEBUG, it seems old-school (ala printf) but thread-safe, reliable and fully configurable (use logfiles, stdout etc..) You'll have to link against [libACE(Adaptive Communication Framework)](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) of course, but it's development packages are easily available in many linux distros per default nowadays. I've been looking over the list from that C++ logging libraries post, mentioned by `Als`, but it seems most people are running into mem leaks with many of the frameworks and boost::Log is not out yet.

Another point is that most logging libraries using streams, for example like this:

```
// from thread 1
mlog(mlog::DEBUG) << "Debug message goes here" << mlog::endl;

// from thread 2
mlog(mlog::INFO) << "Info message goes here" << mlog::endl;
```

will not work as expected in a multithreaded environment, while ACE will perform correctly there.

The output of the above will look something like this:

```
[thread1 | 12:04.23] Debug me[thread2 | 12:04.24] Info message goesssage goes herehere
```